# NiFi Flow for Record Enrichment

Tags: etl, apache-nifi

I am using NiFi 1.11.4 to build a data pipeline where IoT device is sending data in JSON format. Each time I receive data from IoT device, I receive two JSONs;

JSON_INITIAL

```
{
   devId: "abc",
   devValue: "TWOINITIALCHARS23",
}
```

and
JSON_FINAL

```
{
   devId: "abc",
   devValue: "TWOINITIALCHARS45",
}
```

There is a time difference of a few milli seconds with which I receive these two flow files. In my usecase, I need to merge this JSON in such a way that my resultant JSON looks like below (please note removal of TWOINITIALCHARS in both cases;

JSON_RESULT_AFTER_MERGE

```
{
   devId: "abc",
   devValue: "2345",
}
```

Is this something NiFi should be dealing with? If yes, would really appreciate an approach to design relevant flow for this use case.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `devId` is static for a device and not used for the correlation (i.e. `abc` for all messages coming from this device, not `abc` for the first two and then `def` for the next two, etc.), you have a few options:

1. Use `MergeContent` to concatenate the flowfile contents (the two JSON blocks) and `ReplaceText` to modify the combined content to match the desired output. This will require tuning the MC binning properties to limit the merge window to 1-2 seconds (difficult/insufficient if you're receiving multiple messages per second, for example) and using regular expressions to remove the duplicate content.
2. Use a custom script to interact with the device JSON output (Groovy for example will make the JSON interaction pretty simple)

   - If you do this *within* the context of NiFi (via `ExecuteScript` or `InvokeScriptedProcessor`), you will have access to the NiFi framework, so you can evaluate flowfile attributes and content, making this easier (there will be attributes for initial timestamp, etc.).
   - If you do this *outside* the context of NiFi (via `ExecuteProcess` or `ExecuteStreamCommand`), you won't have access to the NiFi framework (attributes, etc.) but you may have better interaction with the device directly.

Comment: yes `devId` is unique to each device so JSON_INITIAL and JSON_FINAL will be received from same device. For (2) problem I am facing is, where do I store JSON_INITIAL while waiting for JSON_FINAL and how to retrieve it inside ExecuteScript